# C# Asynchronous WebRequest with POST

Tags: c#, post, asynchronous, background, webrequest

I am trying to find a C# Asynchronous WebRequest function which will be able to POST variables to a server, and retrieve the response.

I have found many Async WebRequests for C#, but they are not able to POST in them, and when I try to change them to post variables, it will not work.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write your own http implementation (a simple one), it should not be that complicated

Or use google: http://www.debugging.com/bug/8530